# How do I choose the selected values from MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, mongodb-query, livecharts

Given that my data structure in MongoDB is like that the above .
How do I use them for the below codes where I would like to use NodeId as my title and WT's value as my chart values. Do ignore the inputs I have input into title and Values for the ChartValues.

```
 new LineSeries
     {
     Title = "Screws",
    Values = new ChartValues<double> {4.5, 4.5, 4.45, 4.4, 4.4, 4.35, 4.35},
    },
```

Comment: you need to group all values from collection with the same title and get Wt values from group items?

Comment: yes.....actually i need help for the values here and the title here. here i am below manually adding points into the ChartValues and adding into the title which is not what i want. i have 6 objects , all with different WT values. how do i use all 6 to plot this value graph?

Comment: undoable ?): @MaksimSimkin

Comment: yes, sure. But it was not an answer about charts, it was just getting data from mongo

Comment: nvm , can u post again the getting data from mongodb? i can use it for my titles and maybe work my way through the graphs if you do not know how to do it for the graphs

Answer (score 0):

I will assume, that you have a model class for your data, if not, i suggest to create one. My model for your json looks like:

```
public class Value
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public Event @event { get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public string NodeId {get;set;}
    public string FirmwareVER {get;set;}
    public double SignalSTR {get;set;}
    public double battery {get;set;}
    public double CEL {get;set;}
    public double WT {get;set;}
    public string Onlinestat {get;set;}
    public double timeStamp {get;set;}
}
```

In that case you could aggregate your data from collection:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Value>("chart");
var res = collection.Aggregate()
              .Group(x => x.@event.NodeId,
                     x => new {Name = x.Key, WTs = x.Select(r => r.@event.WT).ToList()})
              .ToList();
```

That would be result for some sample data i have used:

[image]

After that you could get the data to your charts, something like:

```
res.Select(r => new LineSeries{Title = r.Name, Values = new ChartValues<double>(r.WTs)});
```

Comment: My question is in a form of a chart . where the title is the name of the line in the graph and the chartvalues are taking the plots to plot the chart

Comment: ok, sorry, i misanderstood it,  winforms charts is not a thing a know anything :)

Comment: its ok . lets just get the title for now . but my class to replace ur value class is the rootobject class , i have added into my question

Comment: the event is an array.

Comment: either event is not an array, or your json is wrong.

Comment: i was able to query something out in the console application using foreach loop

Comment: do you have only one item in your mongo collection?

Comment: and these classes , i followed the utube video to paste into VS as paste speical . i can show u a format of my database document

Comment: i have more than 1

Comment: Do you need a chart for one document in collection, or for all ?

Comment: in json, you have posted event is not an array

Comment: my previous console application code was this to get NodeId and WT but of course it print like 6 for each

Comment: var list = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var dox in list)
            {
               
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", dox["event"]["NodeId"].ToString() , dox["event"]["WT"].ToString()));
            }

Comment: actually , mine is a data collection project thus , my graph variables depend on the WT that is coming in every minute

Comment: This dox["event"]["NodeId"] from your code is exact the same as x.@event.NodeId in mine. You just iterate over all documents in collection, each document has header and event, as simple properties, not as arrays

Comment: my connection string code is the above , i added into my question

Comment: i copied but my _event states "BsonDocument" does not contain a definition for '_event'

Comment: don't understand last comment. You could query your collection as a collection of Rootobject, for that you should in your rootobejct class replace array properties with properties, or as bsondocument. If you do it as bson, you could not get values as rootobject._event.nodeid, but as  doc["event"]["nodeid"]

Comment: i understood the doc["event"]["NodeId"] because its declared in  list then further used in a foreach.. but for ur line of codes i dont understand. maybe abit simpler??

Comment: i also have a seperate event class besides the rootobject class

Answer (score 0):

One of the best features of LiveCharts is that you can plot any type you want, and you are type-safe, considering you want to Plot the `WT` property with a given `IEnumerable` of `Value` type.

```
public class Value
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public Event @event { get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public string NodeId {get;set;}
    public double WT {get;set;}
}
```

You can teach the library to plot any type you want, in this case lets teach it to plot the `WT` property from the `Value` type:

```
var mapper = Mappers.XY<Value>()
                          .X((index,value) => index)
                          .Y((i,v) => (double) v.@event.WT);
Charting.For<Value>(mapper);
```

So in other words this means, every time the library finds a `ChartValues<Value>` instance, it will use the mapper we set. The mapper is really intuitive, it means we will use a zero based index as X coordinate, and the `WT` property as Y.

This line normally needs to be added when you application starts, there are many ways to teach the library how to plot a custom type, for more information pelase see https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Types%20and%20Configuration

And that is all, now you can directly plot `Value` type

```
IEnumerable<Value> dataSource = // source from data base...

new LineSeries
 {
 Title = "Screws",
 Values = dataSource.AsChartValues(), //converts the source to
                                      //an instance of ChartValues<Value>
},
```